# Receive an error customizing collectionView: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an a collection view that get data from an instagram.

`CollectionView` is hooked through an Outlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;
```

There is how i fill cells:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    myCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!cell){

        cell = (myCell *)[myCell cell];
    }

    [self customizeLayoutFlow];
    cell.photo = self.photos[indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

-(void)customizeLayoutFlow{

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(106.0, 106.0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;
}
```

Before you ask, i want to add, that cells load perfectly without `customizeLayoutFlow` method. But i need to customize its layout with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. For some reason i got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 error pointing at     `self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;`.

Before there was no data, `collectionView` just load empty cells but with design i want (means `customizeLayoutFlow` works well).

How to fix that issue?

Update:

I fix problem with another way:

```
#pragma mark - customize layout

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return CGSizeMake(106.0, 106.0);
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{

    return 1.0;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{

    return 1.0;
}
```

So sad i didn't figure out how to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try:

```
-(void)customizeLayoutFlow{

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(106.0, 106.0);
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;

self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
}
```

instead?

Comment: Now it produce same error at lane:     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:_photo[@"images"][@"standard_resolution"][@"url"]]; in cell custom class.

Comment: Method is NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:_photo[@"images"][@"standard_resolution"][@"url"]];, it points for correct image URL. There is no mistake in URL because images loading perfectly for now, see updated code.

Comment: well, it's hard to say what might be wrong. needs good debugging